# How can i access function as a prop in child component that define in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a function as a prop in child `component(DetailViewOfEntity)` that is defined in the parent `component(App.js)`. When I click on the button,I am getting an error that `this.setState` and `obj.detailview` is not defined. Please also look at the image attached below for the exact error that I am getting.

Thank you

**App.js component**

```
import  React from "react";

import DetailViewOfEntity from "./DetailViewOfEntity";


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.viewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);

    this.state = {

        viewEntityState: false,
    
    };

  }


  }
  
  ViewEntity (para) {
    var obj = this;
    this.setState ({
      viewEntityState: true,
    });                                      

    obj.DetailView();//another function
  }

  DetailView() {
    console.log("we are in detail view function");
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        
        <DetailViewOfEntity 
            test = {this.ViewEntity}
        /> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**DetailView Component**

```
import React from "react";

export default class DetailViewOfEntity extends React.Component {
    constructor (props, context) {
        super (props, context);
    }

    UpdateCommentsFromCRM() {

        this.props.test(); //when i call this function, i got an error.
    }
  render () { 
      return (
          <div>

            <button onClick = {() => this.UpdateCommentsFromCRM()}>
            </button>
                     
          </div>
      );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys0Qa.png)

Comment: can you create a quick code sandbox that reproduces the error instance so we can test it

Comment: `this.viewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);` should be `this.ViewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);`

Comment: There is a syntax error. `App` class is getting closed just after constructor.

Comment: @Chamsddine Bouzaine, i never used sandbox, but i attached image (the error that i am getting). thanks

Comment: @ kapil pandey i write in the same way that you write.

Comment: @intekhab, I correct and again run but still getting the same error. thanks

Comment: @Atika.Akmal I will create one for you and share it in the comments and try to reproduce the error for future visitors to try

Comment: @Chamsddine Bouzaine thanks for this favour. could also help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Atika, `this.viewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);` this is the problem. Change the case `this.ViewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);`, I have checked on sandbox and just after this change, it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you are calling :
`this.viewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);`
instead of
`this.ViewEntity = this.ViewEntity.bind(this);`

as @kapil pandey pointed out and here I share with you the working version on code sandbox

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-aryabhata-2k759?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I am thank ful to you. Now I see where i was doing mistake. Again Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving error because of function binding. If you using **'create-react-app'**, you can omit the **constructor** and use **arrow function**. Hopefully, you won't give any error.

Comment: I have changed App.js. Modified code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sYK9tXds4C/